# Add json object to php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, or so I thought. One passes a Javascript object to php via a POST, the other gets data from a JS API which returns another object. I want to join both of these arrays. Here's the sample data and how it is obtained.

Name array which I get from API:-

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "D" [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "v" [3]=> string(1) "i" [4]=> string(1) "d" }
```

User array which is POST'd to my php script:-

```
array (
  'userID' => '12345',
  'time' => 'Monday 26th June 2017 22:12:37 AM',
)
```

Now I use the following to (try) and get both of these pieces of data into the same array to log to a file.

```
$nameoriginal = file_get_contents("/api");
$namejson = json_decode($name);

$user = var_export($_POST, true);

$detailstolog = $namejson + $user;

file_put_contents('/logs/names.log', $detailstolog);
```

However, I get a php error which states the first argument is not a valid array (i.e. $name is not valid). Why is this? What can I do to 'make' it an array?

I think the name 'array' is actually a string, hence the error. How do I make this an array, and is $array1 + $array2 the best way to do this?

I am trying to create something like:-

```
array (
  'name' => 'david',
  'userID' => '12345',
  'time' => 'Monday 26th June 2017 22:12:37 AM',
)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Why is the API returning a string split into an array of characters? Are you sure you're using the API correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't understand where is JSON involved here, you're dealing with arrays, hence no need to *decode* anything from JSON.
The first array seems to be the word "David" split into chars. Then you just need to `implode` it and add it to your `detailstolog` array as the first element:

```
$detailstolog['name'] = implode("", $nameoriginal); // David
$detailstolog += $_POST;
```

Comment: he's getting the data with `file_get_contents("/api")`, that's where JSON is involved.

Comment: Your code won't use the `name` key for the element that's being added.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry about ignoring the key, updated. But he still doesn't need to decode from JSON since he gets an `array` in his `var_dump()` call, see the original post.

Comment: I think that's what he sees after he does `$namejson = json_decode($name);`. If he doesn't decode the JSON he'll get a string like `'["D", "a", "v", "i", "d"]'`.

Comment: `file_get_contents` always returns a string, not an array. How can you implode that?

Comment: Now I'm confused. We have: `$nameoriginal = file_get_contents("/api"); $namejson = json_decode($name);` What is `$name` then?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `$_POST` array to a new variable, then add the name to it.

```
$detailstolog = $_POST;
$name = implode('', $namejson);
$detailstolog['name'] = $name;
```